# Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I am new to GAE and Google Cloud SQL, I have deployed my web services on Google App Engine, sometime my web service are working properly, some time it is giving problem of link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.

Right now I am using free trial, I have create GAE app and cloud SQL at same region ,still i am having this problem.

Ideas?

Comment: Is this still an issue?  If not, were you able to determine what the root cause was?  If so, feel free to post as a self answer.  Otherwise, please provide more information about your environment.  How many connections were successful before you started getting errors?  What is the exact error message?  What instance class are you using for your Cloud SQL instance and for your App Engine instances?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to too many open connections to your mysql instance. Try handling the closing of your jdbc connections after you complete your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application and database instance must be in the same region and your application must be authorize to use this instance

Answer (score 0):

As per this similar [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904272), this message appears when your Cloud SQL instance [activation policy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#activation_policy) is set to 'ON_DEMAND', as it takes some time to start your SQL instance.

Providing a [timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/CommonDataSource.html#setLoginTimeout(int)) during your connection from App Engine will allow your application to wait for the SQL instance to start.